# Passing an Ajax variable to a Codeigniter function

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

I think this is a simple one.

I have a Codeigniter function which takes the inputs from a form and inserts them into a database.  I want to Ajaxify the process.  At the moment the first line of the function gets the id field from the form - I need to change this to get the id field from the Ajax post (which references a hidden field in the form containing the necessary value) instead. How do I do this please?

My Codeigniter Controller function

```
function add()
{
    $product = $this->products_model->get($this->input->post('id'));

    $insert = array(
            'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
            'qty' => 1,
            'price' => $product->price,
            'size' => $product->size,
            'name' => $product->name
        );

    $this->cart->insert($insert);
    redirect('home');
}
```

And the jQuery Ajax function

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
        var dataString = $("input#id") 
        //alert (dataString);return false;  
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "/home/add",  
            data: dataString,  
            success: function() {

            }  
        });
        return false;
    });
```

As always, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

```
   $("#form").submit(function(){
        var dataString = $("input#id") 
        //alert (dataString);return false;  
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "/home/add",  
            data: {id: $("input#id").val()},  
            success: function() {

            }  
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Notice data option in the ajax method. Now you could use `$this->input->post('id')` like you are doing in the controller method.

Comment: Thanks Thorpe, very useful to know.  I just need to change the first line of the codeigniter function so that it isn't looking for the form  input, but the jquery ajax

Comment: "Form inputs" and "AJAX variables" are the same thing, they are both POST parameters sent over an HTTP request. AJAX is not a "thing" that exists, just the name of a methodology.

Answer (score 4):

Why not slam it to the end of

```
url: "/home/add",
```

like

```
url: "/home/add/" + $("input#id").val(),
```

Then I guess codeigniter will treat it like a normal parameter ... ?